# WinRT information: Cannot find a resource with the given key

Tags: xaml, windows-runtime, win-universal-app, resourcedictionary

I am creating a Windows Universal app and now working on the Windows Phone section. I have a Storyboard for a simple button animation placed in the Storyboards.xaml file and I've merged this file with my App.xaml Resources.

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="ms-appx:///Dictionaries/Templates.xaml"/>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="ms-appx:///Dictionaries/Storyboards.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

I locate the storyboard using this code

```
Storyboard sb = App.Current.Resources["StoryboardButton"] as Storyboard;
```

The animation works fine on the main page. But once I go to other page and return back to the main page and re-initiate the animation I get this error

```
WinRT information: Cannot find a resource with the given key.
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

I can't see how you defined StoryboarButton, but try adding x:Key="StoryboardButton" to that definition.